# Display php file data into .tpl (Smarty)

Tags: php, smarty

I have `demo.php` file and over there I created a function for fetching data from database:

Ex:

```
function display() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=" . $_POST['id'];
    $r=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($r);
}
```

Now, I have `user.tpl` file and I want to display the `$row` data coming from above display function into that .tpl file.

I am completely newbie in smarty and don't have much idea about it also not aware with the syntax of it.

How can I achieve this.

Need help....thanks

Comment: Check [`smarty.net - Crash Course`](http://www.smarty.net/crash_course) for getting started. Use `{foreach}` tag to loop through your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function display() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=" . $_POST['id'];
        $r=mysql_query($sql);
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($r);
    }
```

For getting values in smarty template you need to use [**assign**](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign.tpl) Method

```
$smarty->assign('rows',$rows);
```

and in your template file, you can use **[foreach function](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)** to loop through arrays

```
{foreach from=$rows item="row"}
   {$row.name}<br/>
   {$row.Id}    
{/foreach}
```

Comment: is there any need to include demo.php file into user.tpl?

Comment: @kj7 no, it is not required, you can assign values and it will be available in template file

Comment: Thanks....but In project the location of both files are different Ex. the `demo.php` is in `/projectname/demo.php and user.tpl` is in `/projectname/gui/templates/execute/user.tpl`

Comment: @kj7 check {$rows|@print_r} to see if you are getting values in templates

Answer (score 1):

```
function display() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=" . $_POST['id'];
    $r   = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($r);
    return $row;
}
```

assign your result variable into `user.tpl`

```
$this->mysmarty->assign('resArr',$resVar); 
$this->mysmarty->display('user.tpl');
```

using [`foreach`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) you can display the result in your `user.tpl` like this

```
<ul>
{foreach $resArr as $value}
   <li>{$value@key}: {$value}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: is there any need to include `demo.php` file into `user.tpl`?

Comment: :Thanks....but In project the location of both files are different Ex. the `demo.php` is in `/projectname/demo.php` and `user.tpl` is in `/projectname/gui/templates/execute/user.tpl`

Comment: don't consider that and all if you configured properly while smarty installation. it will be available in `.tpl` file if you assign in `php` file